On a efficient algorithm for factoring bivariate polynomials modulo composite modulus assuming the solution is unique
We found and implemented in sage efficient algorithm for factoring
bivariate polynomials modulo composite modulus assuming the solution is unique up to a constant factor.
More formally let $K=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.
Given $F \in K$ in general we can find solution $f,g$ such
that $F=f g$ assuming $f,g$ are unique up to a constant factor
(by constant factor we mean if $f,g$ is solution then another
solution is $g_1=C g,f_1=C^{-1} f$).
The algorithm was tested on 2000 bits integers with unknown factorization by generating
random $f,g$ and then tried to recover them given $F$.
Probably the algorithm may fail on some cases.
So far the failing testcases are both $f,g$ homogeneous or
one of them linear.
In addition the algorithm requires to be given $\deg{f}$ and $\deg{g}$.
===
The algorithm doesn't need the factorization of $n$.
It is tempting to use the algorithm for integer factorization algorithm like computing factors of univariate or homogeneous polynomials, but the current implementation fails on these attack. We suspect the reason for failure is non-uniqueness.
After more testing we still correctly compute the factorization of random polynomials given their degrees and in some case we recognize that such factorization doesn't exist.

Q1 Is this result known?


Q2 Is it of interest?


Is it different to "assume that n is prime and just do as over finite fields"? This will be pretty fast and will also give the correct answer (given your assumption on f, g).

@hans I think it is entirely different. Working over GF(p) always gives correct answer and doesn't fail (assuming correctness of my implementation). Also finding roots of polynomials is closely related to factorization e,g $x^2-A$ is efficiently solvable over GF(p)[x] and my algorithm fails.

When factorization of $n$ s know, one can "assemble" factorization of a given polynomial modulo $n$ from those modulo prime powers dividing $n$ with CRT.

@MaxAlekseyev The algorithm doesn't need the factorization of $n$. I couldn't make the algorithm integer factorization algorithm, non-uniqueness of polynomial factorization is an obstacle for the current implementation.

@joro: It's worth mentioning that property as it puts your algorithm in a different class.

@MaxAlekseyev Thanks, I edited with results about factoring integers.

@MaxAlekseyev I answered the question with sage code and link to 2 page preprint.

We wrote a 2 page preprint on researchgate
Abstract:  We give efficient probabilistic algorithm for factoring bivariate polynomials modulo composite integers with unknown factorization assuming the solution $F(x,y)=g(x,y) f(x,y)$ is unique. The idea is symbolically equating coefficients which leads to overdetermined system of equations which is solved with the sage CAS command `gb=Ideal(J).groebner_basis()'. The algorithm is efficient for random instances, but fails on instances which will lead to the factorization of $n$ like computing roots of univariate polynomials.
Here is the code for the preprint:
def factorgroebner2(F,D_g,D_f,asol=1,retg=False):
    """
    unique solution modulo n up to constant factor
    the factorization of n is not known
    may fail, at least in cases when the polynomial factorization
    leads to factorization of n

    f(x,y)*g(x,y)=F, deg(g)=D_g,deg(f)=D_f

    Author Georgi Guninski, Tue May 14 12:01:23 PM UTC 2024

    Example usage:

    set_random_seed(1);p1=random_prime(2**140);p2=random_prime(p1);n=p1*p2
    Kxy.<x,y>=Integers(n)[]
    D2,D3=2,3
    g2=Kxy.random_element(degree=D2);f2=Kxy.random_element(degree=D3);
    F2=g2*f2
    gg=factorgroebner1(F2,D2,D3)
    F2==gg[0]*gg[1]
    """
    assert D_g != D_f,"deg(f)=deg(g) currently not supported due to non-uniquess"
    Ko=F.parent()
    Kp=F.base_ring()
    XF,YF=F.parent().gens()
    varsx="%s,%s,"%(XF,YF)+",".join(["a_"+str(i) for i in range(1000)])
    Kxy=PolynomialRing(Kp,varsx) #XXX compute
    ge=Kxy.gens()
    X,Y=ge[:2]
    geai=ge[2:]
    F=Kxy(F)
    moxy=Kxy.monomial_all_divisors((X*Y)**max(D_g,D_f))
    moxy += [Kxy(1)]
    mo1=[i for i in moxy if i.degree()<=D_g]
    mo2=[i for i in moxy if i.degree()<=D_f]
    ga=iter(geai)
    g=sum([i*next(ga) for i in mo1])
    f=sum([i*next(ga) for i in mo2])
    G=f*g-F
    J=[]
    D=D_g+D_f
    for dx in range(D+1):
        for dy in range(D+1):
            h=G.coefficient({X:dx,Y:dy})
            if h != 0:   J += [h]
    lg=len([i*j for i,j in g])
    lf=len([i*j for i,j in f])
    gb1=Ideal(J).groebner_basis()
    if gb1==[1]:
        #no solution
        return False
    deg2=[i for i in gb1 if i.degree() != 1]
    if len(deg2) > 1:
        if retg:
            print("error in groebner")#XXX
            return gb1 #XXX
        raise Exception("Fail in grobner basis")
    ai0=deg2[0].variables()[0]
    J += [ai0-asol] #XXX
    gb1=Ideal(J).groebner_basis()
    sol={}
    for h in gb1:
        v=h.variables()[0]
        co0=h.constant_coefficient()
        co1=h.coefficient({v:1})
        sol[v]= -co0/co1
    gs=g.subs(sol)
    fs=f.subs(sol)
    gr=gs(X=XF,Y=YF)
    fr=fs(X=XF,Y=YF)
    gr=Ko(str(gr)) #XXX
    fr=Ko(str(fr)) #XXX
    return gr,fr



Is there a reason why you did not use .variety() method for getting solutions to the system?

I can't make variety() to work over rings, it raises exception ValueError: Coefficient ring must be a field for function 'variety'. Am I missing something?

@MaxAlekseyev Did you see my reply about the variety()?. I am improving the algorithm, there is some minor progress in the univariate case.

Yes, thanks for the insight!
